# Problem with testing input type="file" registered with React-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library, react-hook-form

I am using RHF to validate my form and try to test its file-input with react testing library.
For some reason form remains invalid after mocking file upload.

My form component:

```
imports ....

export default function RegistrationPage(): JSX.Element {

const {
    register,
    formState: {isValid, errors},
  } = useForm<RegisterInputs>(
    {
      mode: 'onBlur',
      shouldFocusError: false,
      reValidateMode: 'onBlur',
    }
  );

return (
  <div className="popup-form__form">
    <form method="post" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmitHandler)}>
      <div className="sign-up">
        <div className="sign-up__load-photo">
          <div className="input-load-avatar">
            <label>
              <input
                data-testid="avatar-input"
                className="visually-hidden" type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
                {...register('avatar',
                   {
                     required: 'avatar is required',
                   }
                )}
              />
            </label>
           </div>
           <div className="sign-up__description">
             {
               errors.avatar && 
               <span style={{fontSize: '0.9em', color: '#e4001b'}}>
                 {errors.avatar.message}
               </span>
             }                
            </div>
            <button
              disabled={!isValid}
              className="btn sign-up__button"
              type="submit"
            >
              Sign up
            </button>
       </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  );
}
```

I removed other redundant fields.
Component works good, the form became valid after submitting image file and submit button becomes enabled.

My test fn:

```
it('should be unlock the submit button if avatar has been uploaded successfully', async () => {

  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <HistoryRouter history={history}>
        <HelmetProvider>
          <RegistrationPage />
        </HelmetProvider>
      </HistoryRouter>
    </Provider>
  );

   const signUpBtn = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sign up' });
   expect(signUpBtn).toBeDisabled();

    const avatarInput = screen.getByTestId('avatar-input');

    const mockAvatar = new File([mock content], 'mock.png', {type: 'image/png'});

    fireEvent.change(avatarInput, { target: { files: [mockAvatar] } });
    fireEvent.blur(avatarInput);

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(signUpBtn).toBeEnabled();
    });
});
```

So this test fails on last string, cause signUpBtn remains disabled
I also removed onChangeHandler with custom file validation from 'register' function in input.
My mocks passed it correct but it seems that form still invalid.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: changing fireEvent to userEvent has solved my problem